# Change Apple store to get local Apps

Tags: iphone, applications

I have an account at the Apple Store Switzerland and I would like to get App’s from the store in China as I live there now. I can’t download Apps like  抖音 because the store in Switzerland doesn’t provide it.  What can I do?

Comment: Use a different Apple ID if needed?

Answer (score 3):

Create a new Apple ID (e.g. [here](https://appleid.apple.com/account#!&page=create)) and use the new one to log into the Chinese App Store.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the country of your Apple ID to get the apps from the relevant store. For details, go through the Apple Support article, [Change the country or region of your Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/kb/KM205111).

If you do not wish to change the country of your Apple ID, you can also create a separate Apple ID with China set as the country. If the desired app is free, the Apple ID can be created without specifying a payment method (in case you do not yet have a credit card in China or do not wish to add one).

On you iOS device, you can log out of iTunes and log in with the new account to access the Chinese App Store. To log out, go to Settings App → **Your Name** → iTunes & App Stores, tap on the Apple ID shown at the top and tap **Sign Out**.